# Spoof subdomain as domain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i've got a subdomain foo.example.com and i want it to point the request to a directory but still be able to get the normal subdomain.

This is what i mean, i got the following directory's:

```
foo
www
   public
        index.php
```

Whenever a user hits foo.example.com i want it to load www/public/index.php but the URL will still be foo.example.com.

I've tried a mod_proxy htaccess, but sadly my hosting doesn't want to turn on mod_proxy.

How could i achieve this with Htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered it i found a solution:

Just replace the 0.0.0.0 with your ip/domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^0.0.0.0$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^0.0.0.0$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```